# Android insmod kernel object on boot

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, boot, init

I am currently trying to insmod a kernel module during the end of the boot process, and so I've created the following entries in init.rc:

```
on post_late_start
    start myscript

on nonencrypted
    class_start late_start
    trigger post_late_start

on property:void.decrypt=trigger_restart_framework
    class_start main
    class_start late_start
    trigger post_late_start

service myscript /data/my_sh.sh
    disabled
    oneshot
```

Then in my /data directory my_sh.sh has the following:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
    log -t mytag -p V "Hello World!"
    insmod mymodule.ko mod_parameter=arg
```

But when I run -- sometimes I do not see the "Hello World" tag when I logcat -s "mytag"  and of course, the insmodded module is not installed either.

What is the proper way of late-inserting a kernel module (it needs to go in after network is up and /data is mounted).  And further -- how do I get the output of insmod into the log so that I can debug?  Any help is appreciated and I can post more details if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

At least since Froyo and still in Lollipop, Android `init` implements `insmod` in [system/core/init/buildin.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/froyo/init/builtins.c).  It is supposed to work directly in an `init*.rc` file:

```
on boot
    insmod /system/lib/modules/your-module.ko.
```

However, at least in Lollipop 5.1, it no longer works, as SELinux rules are enforced.  `init` does not have the required `sys_module` permission.  Therefore the underlying `init_module` system call returns `EPERM`.  This is never reported to anywhere.  The only symptom is that `insmod` commands now fail to load the module, always.

I opened an [AOSP issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184188) on this.  According to Google, this works as intended.  If you want to use kernel modules when SELinux is enforced (which they strongly advice against), you must yourself add the required SELinux permission to `init`.

Comment: How to add the required SELinux permission to init on Andriod 11?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your log, but to insmod you need to give the exact path to the module, because I dont think you will be having mymodule.ko residing in the same place as init.rc is there. So try to give the full path of your ko file. 
Generally it resides in /lib/modules/youdrivername.ko

so check it here first.